# How to correctly parse utf-8 xml with ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I need help to understand why parsing my xml file* with **xml.etree.ElementTree** produces the following errors.

**My test xml file contains arabic characters.*

**Task:**
Open and parse `utf8_file.xml` file.

**My first try:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
with codecs.open('utf8_file.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as utf8_file:
    xml_tree = etree.parse(utf8_file)
```

**Result 1:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 236-238: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**My second try:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
with codecs.open('utf8_file.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as utf8_file:
    xml_string = etree.tostring(utf8_file, encoding='utf-8', method='xml')
    xml_tree  = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
```

**Result 2:**

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

Please explain the errors above and comment on the possible solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Leave decoding the bytes to the parser; do *not* decode first:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
with open('utf8_file.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
    xml_tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
```

An XML file *must* contain enough information in the first line to handle decoding by the parser. If the header is missing, the parser must assume UTF-8 is used.

Because it is the XML header that holds this information, it is the responsibility of the parser to do all decoding.

Your first attempt failed because Python was trying to **encode** the Unicode values again so that the parser could handle byte strings as it expected. The second attempt failed because `etree.tostring()` expects a parsed tree as first argument, not a unicode string.

Comment: Excellent, it appeared to be easier than I thought. Even "utf-8 without BOM" files get parsed correctly.

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM is the standard; *with* BOM is mostly Microsoft wanting to make it easier to autodetect 8-bit encodings other than UTF-8.

Comment: `etree.parse(a_file)` handles Unicode by default. However `etree.fromstring(a_string)` doesn't until Python 3.x (see http://bugs.python.org/issue11033) so to parse a string, you have to encode it manually, like `etree.fromstring(a_string.encode('utf-8'))`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: This question is about Python 2, where file objects produce byte strings, not Unicode. The question concerns the user reading data from a file and manually decoding, which is entirely pointless.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree. This comment is meant to point out a non-obvious behavior for anyone looking into the string-based approach. It's non-obvious that the file-based method handles encoding by default but the string-based method requires pre-encoding.

Comment: You can make it simpler and skip opening it as a file, I have code that does `root = et.parse(sys.stdin).getroot()` and it works just fine.  Tested in Py3.6

Comment: @Marcin: but that requires piping in the XML file. That's a different use case.

Comment: Also works with `sys.argv[1]`, I just used stdin as an example.

Comment: @Marcin: right, that's what you mean. Yes, you can pass in an open file object or a filename.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can see `cElementTree.iterparse()` also tries to decode, which in my case generates `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 293: ordinal not in range(128)`. I am simply passing the file object. Can I help it to decode somehow?

Comment: @TomHemmes: no, not without a traceback and example input, sorry.